# Some pages begin to load and stop on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using Chrome (Version 22.0.1229.94). About 20% of pages simply stop loading after a second or two. Sometimes, I'm able to click an early link after a second or third reload. If I attempt to close the page, it continues to hang for a few (10-30) additional seconds, then closes. However, if I switch to other tabs, it works just fine. If I don't change tabs and wait long enough, it says that there's something on the page that's taking too long to run and offers to let me kill it.

Only a select number of sites fail to load, and they do so consistently. None of the stackexchange sites or google fail, but others like realclearpolitics and wowwiki do. I visit those sites every day, and this is the first time it has failed like this.

If it were just one site, I would say someone messed something up in their deployment. But it seems incredibly peculiar that suddenly, half a dozen popular sites all mysteriously have the same symptoms.

If I attempt to load the pages in Firefox or IE9, they load just fine.

Nothing new has been installed, regarding Chrome or otherwise. Antivirus reports no abnormalities. System is regularly patched. Restarting both chrome and the computer have had no effect.

Comment: What about your DNS settings?

Comment: If it were a DNS issue I wouldn't be able to get just about anywhere. Specifically, the site wouldn't start loading and then just fail.

Comment: And when you changed your DNS settings as part of your test, did you notice any difference in the behaviour of Chrome?

Comment: You can't possibly be serious, but sure I'll humor you. As part of my test, I used a separate browser (note the second to last paragraph) and no problems were noted. This rules out problems with the connection itself, of which DNS is a subset, unless somehow Chrome has some magic override to DNS settings or other connection settings, which I find incredibly unlikely.

Comment: Chrome's cache is legendary for storing things like DNS along with the HTTP cache. Have you tried clearing it out completely? I've learnt to assume nothing when it comes to Chrome. There's a lot of "magic" happening under the hood that is different to other browsers.

Comment: I added the extension from the webstore that allows you to flush it with no benefit. I'm confident that a DNS issue wouldn't exhibit the kinds of symptoms I'm seeing. For what it's worth, realclearpolitics stopped exhibiting the issues last night, but the WoW sites I frequent still are. This makes me think it's something to do with a bad advert that's killing the page. I've noticed that the pages that load snappy all say "Our ads support our site. Please whitelist our ads" where the ads normally are. (cont...)

Comment: This is consistent with the chrome notification of a page script running excessively, and with the fact that the page works fine for the first few seconds occasionally and then freezes. For now, I've simply added a few lines in the hosts file to block some of the ads (I'm not opposed to ads, so I don't want to use an ad blocker) and it seems to be working okay. This was done after the RCP stuff was working good, and now it's a 50/50 shot on the WoW sites.

Comment: Good to hear that you seem to have narrowed it down to errant ads. A good enough reason to block Flash or JavaScript if there ever was one.